# Tell base class function to do different things dependent on the calling subclass

Tags: oop, python-3.x

In a base class, I have the following code:

```
@staticmethod
def _split_on_empty_lines(file_contents):
    """generator that yields sections of a file separated by empty lines"""

    section = ''
    for line in file_contents:
        if line.strip():
            section += line
        else:
            _section_yield_function()
            section = ''
```

The `_section_yield_function()` is supposed to do different things in the two subclasses. In the first one, it should check whether the line after the empty line is empty as well before yielding it; in the other one, it should not perform that check.

I read that the calling class of a function is not known inside the function context, so what would be a good way to implement this kind of behaviour?

Comment: Can your `staticmethod` be a `classmethod` instead? Or even an instance method?

Comment: Implement it in the sub-classes instead of the base class? If the behaviour should vary by class, are you sure it *should* be static?

Comment: Thanks, I think this solves it. I am not too confident with OOP decorators, so I just overlooked that with `@classmethod` I can access `cls`.